# How to add/change an imported function in a python package?

Tags: python, import, pip, jupyter-notebook, package

I am using google colab as my working environment. I'm doing

```
!pip install package
```

and then importing the modules.

Now, I want to add/change something to one of the functions. How can I do this?
(In my case, instead of appending data, I want it to create separate new files for each iteration).
I can shift to Jupiter-notebook too.
The package is deeply cut. I want to change a particular function (evaluate.py) to get a customized output. Do I have to download the package in my system and then change it locally or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: please provide more specific information to your problem

Comment: Easy. `functionInTheModule = yourFunction` if you did a wildcard import I believe. Then you can do `functionInTheModule()`, which is the same as `yourFunction()`

Comment: Are you trying to modify an existing imported function?

Comment: @Steezy yes, there is the package deeplabcut. I want to change one of its function.As,I'm using colab I have to first install it and then import it into the environment.

Comment: @BlueStaggo Could you show me an example?

Comment: @BlueStaggo The fuction I want to change is here https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/0502a893d2fd5af37c6c3ef6ede917fb960ad5b0/deeplabcut/pose_estimation_tensorflow/evaluate.py#L20

Comment: Why would you need to change a package's function anyways? Just create a new one with a different name if you don't need to.